# what is the best way to code continuous X and Y movement of a sprite node in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, nstimer

I am creating my first sprite kit game and i am having difficulty coding my hero's movement. Here is how i coded my hero's movement in objective-c in a single view application using touch down and touch up inside IBactions. I am trying to repeat the same results in a sprite kit game in swift.

```
-(IBAction)LeftArrowTapped:(id)sender; {

[self heroMovementTimerMethodLeft];

}
-(IBAction)RightArrowTapped:(id)sender; {

[self heroMovementTimerMethodRight];

}
-(IBAction)TouchEndedLeft:(id)sender; {

[heroMovementTimerLeft invalidate];

} 
-(IBAction)TouchEndedRight:(id)sender; {

[heroMovementTimerRight invalidate];

}
-(void)heroMovementTimerMethodLeft {

heroMovementTimerLeft = [NSTimer 
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero target:self 
selector:@selector(heroMovementLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)heroMovementTimerMethodRight {

heroMovementTimerRight = 
[NSTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero target:self 
selector:@selector(heroMovementRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)heroMovementLeft{

hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x -.5, hero.center.y );
}

-(void)heroMovementRight{

hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x +.5, hero.center.y );
}

-(void)enemyMovementTimerMethod {

enemyMovementTimer =  
[NSTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfEnemy target:self 
selector:@selector(enemyMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

I understand that in sprite kit i will have to replace my IBactions with touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods but how do i repeat the coded results in swift. Here is how i am trying now

```
let heroMovementLeft = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width - 5,  
duration: 3)
```

But i get an error, i have also tried

```
let heroMovementLeft = CGPointMake(hero.position.x -5 ,
hero.position.y)
```

I apologize i am very new to swift and sprite kits

Comment: Perhaps setting the velocity will be what you are looking for?  You would need a physics body with no gravity and a few other things turned off.

Comment: @gliderman could you give me an example? and what exactly do i need turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Using SKActions like you trying is fine.
Are you actually running the action, because from your code it seems like you are not.

```
 let heroMovementLeft = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width - 5,duration: 3)
 hero.runAction(heroMovementLeft) // This is missing in your code example
```